I imported my wallet, but cannot sign. What does that mean?
I have a bitcoin wallet. It has hundreds of unknown transactions. I imported it into Electrum. I can freeze and unfreeze the wallet. I can receive, I can partially send. I cannot sign however. Any help with this issue will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is known as a watch-only wallet, and it's simply a method of tracking bitcoins without being able to spend them. It's often used as part of a scam, where exactly did you get this wallet?
